# Autosys pass trigger job name as a command parameter

Tags: autosys

I want to implement 'simplest failure notifier' jil.
That jil should depend on set of jobs and it should be triggered at once when any of those dependent jils changed their state to failed.
Moreover I would like to pass the name of the failed job as a parameter to the command to report it.
Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you will have to structure it so each regular job will have a respective failure detection job, with each of those redirecting to your main failure handler job.

JOB_ONE_FAILED has a run condition of failure(JOB_ONE), it executes SOMETHING_FAILED and passes it "JOB_ONE" as a parameter.

JOB_TWO_FAILED has a run condition of failure(JOB_TWO), it executes SOMETHING_FAILED and passes it "JOB_TWO" as a parameter.

etc.

Comment: I have about 20 jobs that I need to depend on. Do you propose me to add another 20 to achieve the goal?